# printing JSON values in Python

Tags: json, python-2.7

I've search a ton of articles here and elsewhere via the Googles, plus read a few related docs over at docs.python.org and still stuck.

I am getting a response from an API like below:

```
{"status":"active","perms":1,"data":{"40332895":{"user_values":{"delta":-203,"value":53.32,"order":42509}}}}
```

I have no problem printing the 'status' or 'data'. However, all I can grab is the name of the *user_values*, not the date inside them.

Been at it for way to long and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Fairly new to Python and if I need to change how I am doing this because it is bad practices or there is an easier way to get the results I am looking for, please let me know.

**Code:**

```
import json
import urllib2

url = urllib2.urlopen('http://URLofAPI.com')
json_url = json.load(url)

api_result = json_url

for doc in api_result['data']['40332895']['user_values']:
    print doc
```

outputs:
delta
value
order

what I really want to get is the value of them (i.e.: '-203', '53.32', '42509').

I am basically trying to save that data into a list\dict (individually or separately), then print it with other data. I have tried all sorts of things and cannot manage it. I am sure it's probably something super easy that I missing, but it's driving me nuts. :)

Also, I was really expecting the below to give me '42509', but I get an error:

```
for doc in api_result['data']['40332895']['user_values']['order']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for the keys of the user_values dictionary, and getting them.  Try this:

```
uv = api_result['data']['40332895']['user_values']
for doc in uv:
    print uv[doc]
```

Comment: That's exactly what my problem was. Wow, 10 minutes to get an answer. I shouldn't have beat my head against the wall for so long until I asked for help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your example `api_result['data']['40332895']['user_values']` is a dictionary.
If you iterate over a dictionary you will get the keys. This is the case in your original example and in mgkrebbs answer.
However if you iterate over the `.iteritems()` (or `.items()`) of the dictionary you get the (key, value) pairs in a tuple:

```
uv = api_result['data']['40332895']['user_values']
for key,value in uv.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

If you only need the values, you iterate over `.itervalues()`

```
uv = api_result['data']['40332895']['user_values']
for value in uv.itervalues():
    print value
```

Or if you only need the values as a list:

```
my_list = api_result['data']['40332895']['user_values'].values()
```

The difference between .itervalues() and .values() is that the former gives you an iterable (an object which returns one value at a time, but does not create the structure in memory), while the latter gives you a list.